# Splitting string into sections while maintaining all non-word characters

Tags: php, regex, string, encryption

I'm working on an encryption function just for fun (for a non-production environment). Currently running my encrypt function like this:

```
encrypt("This is a string.");
```

Produces the following string:

```
GnulHynkAfdsGknp AfdsGknp Wgbf GknpLnugBuipAfdsCbhgByfg.
```

This is perfect, exactly what I wanted and expected - however, now I'm trying to write a decrypt function. Every character that is encrypted will have a single capital letter followed by 3 non-capital letters (As you can see from the example above).

My plan was to run `preg_split()` to get the different letters of the string.

Here is my current PHP code (pattern `([A-Z][a-z]{3})`):

```
print_r(preg_split("/([A-Z][a-z]{3})/", $string));
```

There are a couple of problems with this. While testing, I discovered that it is not returning what I expected, the return is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] =>  
    [5] => 
    [6] =>  
    [7] =>  
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => .
)
```

(Via [eval.in](https://eval.in/945161))

So this has the proper amount of returns, but they are all blank. Why are all the values blank?

Another thing that I thought of was that I needed to include other characters such as spaces, commas, periods etc in the `preg_split()` return. In the return I got from eval.in, it appears as though the final period has been included. Is this true for spaces and other characters as well, or do I need to do something special in cases of these characters?

Comment: Try using this as your regex: `(?=[A-Z][a-z]{3})` with split

Comment: @Gurman Well that solves the issue of the blank values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "*splitting*" on those matches so they are removed.  You want `preg_match_all` or use `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

```
print_r(preg_split("/([A-Z][a-z]{3})/",
                   $string,
                   null,
                   PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much! Will accept answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

You should remove capturing group `()` and use `preg_match_all`.

```
$text = "GnulHynkAfdsGknp AfdsGknp Wgbf GknpLnugBuipAfdsCbhgByfg.";
preg_match_all("/[A-Z][a-z]{3}|(?: |,|\.)/", $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gnul
            [1] => Hynk
            [2] => Afds
            [3] => Gknp
            [4] =>  
            [5] => Afds
            [6] => Gknp
            [7] =>  
            [8] => Wgbf
            [9] =>  
            [10] => Gknp
            [11] => Lnug
            [12] => Buip
            [13] => Afds
            [14] => Cbhg
            [15] => Byfg
            [16] => .
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. But what about the non-word characters like space, slash, period etc?

Comment: Just add `|.` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That wouldn't work, because they would be combined with encrypted characters. They would have to be their own select group - AbraCadaver's answer gives me the proper output

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Updated!

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: *"That wouldn't work..."*, test it before saying that: https://3v4l.org/B1A7C

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I guess I had a misunderstanding of the | character in the context. Thank you!